# Is it possible to render a react fragment to an image without spinning up a server

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer, playwright, jest-image-snapshot

I would like to render a react fragment to an image similar to how `react-test-renderer` renders html, without needing to create a route for the test and spin up a complete server.
So I would like to do something similar to this:

```
test("test is exemplified", () => {
  const image = renderer.create(
    <div class="container">
      <component-under-test />
      <component-under-test boolean-attribute />
      <component-under-test className="some-class"/>
    </div>).screenshot('./test-index.tsx');

  expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot();
})
```

Is it possible to get puppeteer or playwright to render an app inline like that?